# pt-query-digest for PROCESSLIST doesn't work for me

Tags: mysql, pt-query-digest

```
pt-query-digest --processlist h=host,D=db,u=uname,p=pwd --interval 0.5 > /tmp/process_qry.log
```

just says "Reading from STDIN ..."

I used to do this with MAATKIT all the time and it worked fine. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
[~]$ pt-query-digest --version
pt-query-digest 2.2.20

mysql > select version();
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 5.5.53    |
+-----------+
```

I tried posting this on Percona's forums and that didn't work either.

Thanks,

Ken

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Someone on Percon'a forum answered my question!

I needed to include "--output slowlog"

pt-query-digest --processlist h=host,D=db,u=uname,p=pwd --output slowlog > /tmp/process_qry.log

Comment: Is it normal the task doesn't finish? How long does it take?